# Odoo: Where to edit the overview of customer invoices?

Tags: odoo, invoices

I'm new to Odoo and I'm looking for a way to add/edit columns in the overview of customer invoices.

Does anyone know which files to edit? Or how this "overview screen" is called so I can look it up better?

Link to screenshot of overview screen: http://oi58.tinypic.com/2prtyk0.jpg

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Now that i discovered where the tree view is located, i want to add my field "levertermijn".
I tried the following code:  

    `<record model="ir.ui.view" id="invoice_tree">
  <field name="name">account.invoice.tree.inherit</field>
  <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_tree_view"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
   <field name="state" position="after">
    <field name="levertermijn"/>
    </field>
   </field>
 </record>`

This gives the error: ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: account.invoice_tree_view" while parsing...

Answer (score 0):

The VIEW of this "TREE" is defined in

```
addons/account/views/account_invoice_view.xml
```

Which has the code like this:

```
        <record id="invoice_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">account.invoice.tree</field>
        <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree decoration-info="state == 'draft'" decoration-muted="state == 'cancel'" string="Invoice">
                <field name="partner_id" groups="base.group_user" string="Customer"/>
                <field name="date_invoice"/>
                <field name="number"/>
                <field name="commercial_partner_id" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="reference" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="name" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="journal_id" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="company_id" groups="base.group_multi_company" options="{'no_create': True}"/>
                <field name="user_id"/>
                <field name="date_due"/>
                <field name="origin"/>
                <field name="amount_total_signed" sum="Total Amount"/>
                <field name="residual_signed" sum="Residual Amount"/>
                <field name="currency_id" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="company_currency_id" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="state"/>
                <field name="type" invisible="context.get('type',True)"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use developer mode to know the name of the view what you want change/edit/inherit/..etc,

Go to **Administrator => About Odoo => Activate Developer Mode** then return to the view and you will see near to the name of the current view a **Drop-down list**  with name `Debug View#xx` click there and choice `Edit TreeView/FormView/...etc` after that you are going to see the definition of the current view, in this way you will know what view you need to inherit/edit/..etc

I hope this will help you!

Comment: Thank you, this is convenient to find this quickly!

Comment: `<record model="ir.ui.view" id="my_invoice_tree_inherit"> <field name="name">my.invoice.tree.inherit</field> 
     <field name="model">account.invoice</field> 
     <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_tree"/> 
     <field name="arch" type="xml"> 
        <field name="state" position="after"> 
             <field name="levertermijn"/> 
        </field> 
    </field> 
</record>`
**1. The id should be different to the original, in this case the original id is invoice_tree thats why I called it my_invoice_tree_inherit, 2. The ref should be the id of the original view invoice_tree**